# Cant use .send when its not used in client.on(ready) discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im trying to make a bot that sends a message every 24 hours at a specific channel, but the

```
client.channels.cache.get('ID').send('Test Mode');
```

only works in

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
```

Im using  crontab for the loop

Comment: Have you considered using something like a [Webhook](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) and `cron` to automate tasks which happen at a certain interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to send the message when the bot is not ready?
Try to start the loop in the `client.on("ready", () => {});` 
If it doesn't work, please send the full code (without the token)
Have a nice day!

Comment: It works, so i have to write the whole code in the client.on(ready)?

Comment: All things related to the bot must be in the `client.on("ready", () => {});` simply because the bot is ready to do some things